# C# passing data between classes

Tags: c#, class

Just wondering how people would go about this.  Say I have one class that creates and populates a Treeview which is then added to a Winform.

I have another class that is dependent upon data within the Treeview.  So for example, when a user clicks on a specific node in the Treeview, class b needs that information that the node holds so that it can perform some calculation and display the result.

Would it better practise to simply pass a reference to the Treeview to the second class, or just the data that it needs?  Or would it be okay to set the Treeview as static and use events so that the new class can access the treeview directly when a node is clicked on?

Thanks.

Comment: When are you creating the instance of class b?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would raise an event in the class that holds the treeview. That is, define a delegate and an event your class has. Then the depending class can subscribe to that event and act on the data included in the event. As I understand your question the depending class doesn't need to do anything with the treeview and should therefor not know about the treeview.

```
public delegate void YouControlHandler(int relevantData1, string relevantData2);
public class ClassContainingTreeView
{
    public event YouControlHandler TreeViewClickedEvent;
    public void OnTreeViewClicked(object sender, EventArgs)
    {
        // Handle request locally first and extract relevantData1/2
        if(TreeViewClickedEvent != null)
            TreeViewClickedEvent(relevantData1, relevantData2);
    }
}

public class DependingClass
{
     ClassContainingTreeView yourObject = new ClassContainingTreeView();

     public DependingClass()
     {
         yourObject.TreeViewClickedEvent += new YouControlHandler(EventHandler);
     }

     protected void EventHandler(int relevantData1, string relevantData2)
     {
             // Handle event
     }
}
```

Comment: I think this is what I want to achieve.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi Tomas, are you declaring the delegate outside of the class here at global namespace level?  Sorry if it's a stupid question, I'm new to delegates.  Thanks.

Comment: @Darren: Yes, that is how you do it. My code doesn't compile probably.. just wrote it form my head. Read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9aackb16.aspx. If it is not clear just ask again.

Answer (score 5):

Just pass the data.

You do not want a class to be tightly coupled to a UI control.

---

As an aside, why do you think you need to make the TreeView static in order to consume events from it?

You can subscribe to an event from objects that are not static.

Comment: But now you have some other type of dependency, I would actually go for my solution with an event instead. That makes it even more lously coupled and more classes could act on the actual "click" in the treeview.

Comment: @Tomas Jansson - Really? With TreeView specific event arguments? Using primitives (or DTOs) will ensure less coupling. If the class can work with a couple of strings and an int, that's loose coupling.

Comment: @Oded: I think you are getting it wrong. The class that has the treeview responds to the treeview event. When it is done handling the event it raises an own defined event that the treeview has been clicked with relevant data.

Comment: @Tomas - I see. That's not a bad solution, though pretty similar in the end result.

Comment: @Oded: It's a big difference... Why do the class that has the TreeView need to depend on the depending class? Circular reference and that is not good!

Comment: My main concern is the actual coupling of classes.  I am a few months into an internship and I have found that my earlier code is quite (to put it mildly) untidy and very highly coupled.  I am trying to refactor, into nicer, looser coupled and more maintainable code.  I think events are probably the way to go.  Thanks.

Comment: @Tomas Jansson - That's why I say pass the _data_. And the class the has the `TreeView` _already_ has a reference to the class that needs the data.

Comment: @Darren Young - Don't make the mistake and assume that events mean you are not coupled. The _least_ coupled methods just use primitives.

Comment: @Oded, thanks. That's my focus at present.  I don't just want to be writing working code, I want it to be maintainable and loosely coupled.  I am aware that obviously classes will be coupled to work, however keeping it to a minimum is mmy concern. It's got that bad, I lose sleep over it  :)  I'll get there in the end, it's just practice and experience I guess.

Comment: @Oded: I definitely think going for events in this case is the right way to go. When having event like this you can be much more flexible, let say you implement another class that also needs to do something when the treeview is clicked, should we update the dependent class in that case? No, what we should do is just to subscribe to the event that we are exposing.

Comment: @Darren Young: Good luck from me too :).

Comment: @Oded @Tomas  Thanks for the kind words :)

Comment: @Tomas, is this a simple version of the Observer pattern?

Comment: @Darren - .NET events are pretty much the native .NET version of the Observer pattern. Well spotted :)

Comment: @Darren and @Oded: Glad to hear that someone remebers the name of pattern, that's something I should learn :)... that is, remeber the name of patterns. Hope it works out for you Darren.

Comment: @Tomas - Head First Design Patterns is a good book to read and can help with remembering the patterns it uses.

Comment: @Oded: Will put it up on the list of book I want to read. Although, the problem isn't that I don't understand the patterns... just remember their names :). But will definitely look up the book, thanks!

Comment: @Tomas @Oded  I am currently reading HF Design Patterns and agree that it is really good.  I like the simple yet effective style that they propagate.

Comment: Hi Again :)  Can I just ask something. Upon form load, I create the treeview object, which internally populates the actual Treeview and adds it to the winform.  Now, in another class is where I want to check for any interaction with the treeview, which is controlled by the object created in Form Load, do I therefore have to pass a reference to that object through to the new class?  Thanks.

Comment: @Darren Young - If you want to subscribe to the events exposed by this object, then yes, you need a reference to it.

Comment: @Oded - Thanks.  I have set up the Treeview object as a Singleton and simply include an instance wherever I want to register an observer.  It works well in this case.  Thanks for yours and @Tomas help.